# Remove trailing commas after transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to transpose a column off data, however, it still leaves trailing commas.  Can someone help to clean this up?

```
Sub ReorganizeData()
  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, Index As Long
  Dim Sheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Const Interval As Long = 1000

  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  For X = 1 To LastRow Step Interval
    Index = Index + 1
    Cells(Index, "B") = Application.Trim(Join(Application.Transpose(Cells(X, "A").Resize(Interval).Value), ","))
  Next

  Range("A:A").Delete xlShiftToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: Will the number of trailing commas be the same each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below would be a quick fix but in the process actually suppress any two consecutive commas in the resulting strings regardless of position - if that may be of any concern. The trailing commas are due to joining empty cells, so there may be a better approach to just avoid joing empty cells in the first place

```
Sub ReorganizeData()
  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, Index As Long
  Dim Sheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Const Interval As Long = 1000

  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  For X = 1 To LastRow Step Interval
    Index = Index + 1
    Cells(Index, "B") = Application.Trim(Join(Application.Transpose(Cells(X, "A").Resize(Interval).Value), ","))
    'Replaces any ",," substring in the above resulting string with an empty string
    Cells(Index, "B") = Replace(Cells(Index, "B"), ",,", "")
    'Cleans up any possible extra single trailing ","
    If Mid(Cells(Index, "B"), Len(Cells(Index, "B")), 1) = "," Then
        Cells(Index, "B") = Left(Cells(Index, "B"), Len(Cells(Index, "B")) - 1)
    End If
  Next

  Range("A:A").Delete xlShiftToLeft
End Sub
```

Edit: @ A Hugues - are you saying this is what you are observing after putting the above code to the test? If so I am confused, the extra lines that have been added compared to your original code just consist of replacing any ",," substring within your resulting strings with an empty string - + cleaning up any extra single "," still trailing after that. If that is actually the case - is there any chance you can test as an aside that the replace function actually works as expected?

FYI I confirm this works fine on my end. I have also added a couple comments in the code for clarity

Edit2: there also potentially is the possibility that the 0s that you are seeing now actually already existed in your original strings but went unnoticed after what seemed to be a long series of traling commas, would be great if you could provide a confirmation on this

Comment: this approach doesn't remove the trailing commas, it inserts zeros in between them?